# Chronbach's Alpha of Likert Item

Tags: likert, consistency

My questionnaire is consists of ten 5-point scaled likert items. If the likert items have a good chronbach alpha, is it ok to take the average score of 10 items?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no. Likert scales are ordinal and, therefore, adding them isn't right.

Practically, yes. People do this all the time.

But a better method would be to do a factor analysis (accounting for the fact that the data are ordinal) and using that, rather than a simple sum. In my experience, though, it winds up not making that much difference.

Comment: If you are bothering to do factor analysis, you might as well use the factor scores. You can then use standard methods to compare them.

Comment: Thank u again sir. Sorry, i accidentally deleted my previous comment.